# Is it a good choice to adapt rest api to meet exact front web client use cases?

Tags: rest, angular, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

I use Angular2 with django rest framework on back.
Is it a good practice to consider designing a rest API that meets exactly front implementation use cases. routes, which fields to include... ? This makes front project far more maintainable than interacting with a general API that gives all data access possibilities without caring about font needs (some overhead include:  unused fields, double front models for UI + for API).

Comment: There really is no one right answer to this kind of question.  If Angular2 is **the only** accessor to the API then that's one thing;  if there are other accessors to the API, then the decision will likely come down to how closely the API shares methods with these different resources;  It would make very little sense, for example, to repeat an entire API function to only remove one field.  In this, as in any other aspect of design, DRY is *probably* better.

Comment: You can [limit which fields to return](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#limiting-fields). It is not difficult in DRF. Just try to keep resourses as general as possible. For example if you show active tasks make `/tasks/?status=active` instead of `/active_tasks/` even if you don't need any other tasks.